# Watir Webdriver <script> Element exists?

Tags: webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver, locate

I'm attempting to determine after a page loads whether text within a script may be located using Watir WebDriver.  I am using Watir-WebDriver to automate our test effort.  I cannot figure out how to locate the element and verify the value.  Any help?

```
<script><!--
...
     s.events="event9"
...
//--></script>
```

So, I guess I'm wondering is it possible to search for text within a HTML script using watir webdriver?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: Below is the script.

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "watir-webdriver-performance"
require "rspec"
require "headless"

include Watir
require 'logger'

#path store file: script, data file, logs
path = File.dirname(__FILE__)

#create log file
name_log = 'TEST_0001_bsro_validation_suite'
file = File.open(path + '/logs/' + name_log + '_logFile.log', File::WRONLY | File::APPEND | File::CREAT)
logger = Logger.new(file)
logger.info("=> TEST: 0004_bsro_validation")

#open internet browser
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff

#go to rebrand website with login info.  this may need to be removed.
test_site = 'http://*****:*****@fcac-rebrand.laughlin.com/'
browser.goto(test_site)
load_secs = browser.performance.summary[:response_time]
logger.info("=> Page Load Time: #{load_secs}")

zipcode_input = browser.text_field(:id => 'universal-selectorZip')


# select year; progressive selection
year_select = browser.select_list(:id => 'universal-year')
browser.select_list(:id => 'universal-year', :disabled => 'disabled').wait_while_present

if year_select.exists?
  year_select.select '2010'
else
  logger.info("=> ERROR: Year Select Not Available")
end

# select make; progressive selection
make_select = browser.select_list(:id => 'universal-make')
browser.select_list(:id => 'universal-make', :disabled => 'disabled').wait_while_present

if make_select.exists?
  make_select.select 'Volkswagen'
else
  logger.info("=> ERROR: Make Select Not Available")
end

# select model; progressive selection
model_select = browser.select_list(:id => 'universal-model')
browser.select_list(:id => 'universal-model', :disabled => 'disabled').wait_while_present

if model_select.exists?
  model_select.select 'Jetta'
else
  logger.info("=> ERROR: Model Select Not Available")
end

# select submodel; progressive selection
submodel_select = browser.select_list(:id => 'universal-submodel')
browser.select_list(:id => 'universal-submodel', :disabled => 'disabled').wait_while_present

if submodel_select.exists?
  submodel_select.select '2.0T TDI Sedan'
else
  logger.info("=> ERROR: Submodel Select Not Available")
end

# input zip code; progressive selection

if zipcode_input.exists?
  zipcode_input.set '53202'
else
  logger.info("=> ERROR: ZIP Code Select Not Available")
end

browser.button(:id => 'universal-submit-tires-quote').click

browser.script.html.include? "event49"

browser.close
```

I should add that the event is event49 not 9 in this case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zeljko has the right approach. However, it would fail if/when there are multiple scripts on the page and the one you want is not first.

If there are multiple script elements, you will have to iterate over them to see if one of the scripts has the value.

```
browser.scripts.any?{ |s| s.html.include? "event9" }
#=> true
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Justin.  I am getting the following error: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError).  Not sure if this is related to the solution.

Comment: Can you update your question with your entire script and a page that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Updated in original post.  URL is in script with username and password.  Thanks!

Comment: The exception is only occasionally occurring, which leads me to believe it is a timing issue where watir is interacting with the page before it has finished loading. Other than catching the exception and retrying, I am not sure how else to determine if this page is done loading.

Comment: Thanks!  I will post separately to figure out the DOM timing issue.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
browser.script.html.include? "event9"
#=> true
```